# How to set default theme while creating new site or subsite

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-enterprise, theme

I want to create a new subsite using default publishing template in sharepoint 2007, once created i want a different theme to be applied to site, how can i change the default theme ans use a different theme as default?

kindly help. Urgent.

Comment: is this through powershell, visual studio, feature deployment, web services, UI, etc??

Comment: @DaveWise sharepoint setting through site setting etc, no custom code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply theme which is applied to default publishing template or you need to apply separate theme for your new sub site only?

Yes it is possible. Consider you have your custom theme. Now you need to navigate to the location "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\". Here select your site template. In your case, select PUBLISHING -> XML -> Onet.xml. Open the xml file and add new tag under configuration to call our custom page with parameter as your custom theme. In custom page, we need to apply our custom theme and redirect to default page.[Reference Here](http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2006/03/automatically-applying-theme-to-site.html)

Comment: I have main site wit say `TestTemplate` theme, Whenever i create a new subsite using default publihing template(not custom ) `TestTemplate` theme should be automatically applied to it. Is it possible?

Comment: Create new site using default publishing template. Apply your TsetTemplate theme and save that site as template. Now you can create any sites using that site template which will have TestTemplate theme applied by default.

Comment: That i know, i have given that as temp solution to the client but they want to use default SP template. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Consider you have your custom theme. Now you need to navigate to the location "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\". Here select your site template. In your case, select PUBLISHING -> XML -> Onet.xml. Open the xml file and add new tag under configuration to call our custom page with parameter as your custom theme. In custom page, we need to apply our custom theme and redirect to default page. Please refer the link below for reference. http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2006/03/automatically-applying-theme-to-site.html